# Compiler error: 'private' renders variables inaccessible within the class

Tags: c++, private, member

Alright, I'm doing the exercises from C++ Primer 5th Edition, and I'm currently trying to enrich a class that's been passed around this chapter as practice. Specifically, for those who don't have the book, the chapter asks you to write a class, and slowly you add features to it. So far, my code executed correctly. Now, when I try to apply access specifiers to hide the implementation, I get an error. First things first, here's my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
    friend std::istream& read(std::istream& is, Person& item);
    friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os,const Person& item);


    public:
    Person() = default;
    Person(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2):
        name(s1),address(s2) {}

    std::string ret_name() const {return name;};
    std::string ret_address() const {return address;};

    private:
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

std::istream& read(std::istream& is, Person& item)
{
    is >> item.name >> item.address;
    return is;
}

std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os,const Person& item)
{
    os << item.name << " " << item.address;
    return os;
}
```

The error says that 'within this context (the two lines where the constructors are defined) 'name' and 'address' are private'. Now, as far as I got this concept, private members CAN be accessed by class member functions, yet here, the constructors themselves can't. The non-member code doesn't give an error (since I've made those two functions friends).

What could be wrong? I'm quite new in this concept so I can't see what went awry.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1: I tried commenting and moving the lines at which the constructor is declared. The error 'within this context' seems to point at those lines again, so it might not be the constructor after all.

Comment: Indentation would be nice. Replace your tabs with spaces.

Comment: you declared the two methods as friend. So those two only can access private variables outside the class!

Comment: When I try this on ideone ( http://ideone.com/ipEUXS ) there's no error showing up. BTW: could be a nice idea to declare the `ret_` function to return `const std::string &`

Comment: Is that a copy-and-paste or did you retype the code? Typos have a wonderful ability to disappears on retyping. And is it the entire code?

Comment: Compiles correctly for me. I had to make sure the compiler was using C++11 by specifying -std=c++11 because of `= default`. Apart from that it worked.

Comment: @Stefano: but, isn't it counter-intuitive for the constructors (which are ALREADY members of the class) to not be able to access its private members? That actually goes against the definition of private.

Comment: Molbdnilo, actually your second question solved it for me. I forgot that next to the header file on C::B, I had another file open that had 2 lines that tried to access the members directly. How silly of me! 

Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem with the class definition. The reason of the errors can be either other code that uses this definition incorrectly or maybe your compiler does not support specifier `default`. Try to substitute your default constructor for

```
Person() {}
```

and compile your code anew.